# How to find behavior ID in Ajax calendar extender

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, calendar

I am using Ajax calender extender for selecting multiple dates.

```
    <Ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="Server"  
BehaviorID="CalendarExtender2"  TargetControlID="TextBox8"  
PopupButtonID="Image1" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateselect" OnClientHidden="calendarhidden" OnClientShown="setInitialValue"/>
```

This is the Java script code.

```
function dateselect(cntrl) {

    var calendarBehavior1 = $find("CalendarExtender2");
    var date = calendarBehavior1._selectedDate.format("M/dd/yyyy");
    var hiddencontrol = $get('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
    if (hiddencontrol.value.indexOf(date) == -1)
        hiddencontrol.value += date + ";";
    tag1 = 1;
}

function calendarhidden(cntrl) {

    var calendarBehavior = $find("CalendarExtender2");
    if (tag1 == 1)
        calendarBehavior.show();
    $get('<%=TextBox8.ClientID %>').value = $get('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

But thing is I want to make these java script functions generalized one. So that I can use for other calender extender.
IF I am passing **this**

`OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateselect(this)"`

How to find behavior ID using this? Please help on this.

Comment: As behavior id is defined by you and you have full control on it, why not just change the `dateselect` accept behavior id as second parameter and pass it like `OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateselect(this,'CalendarExtender2')"?`

Comment: I tried this...
function dateselect(cntrl,CalBeh) {
     var date = CalBeh._selectedDate.format("M/dd/yyyy");
    var hiddencontrol = $get('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
    if (hiddencontrol.value.indexOf(date) == -1)
    hiddencontrol.value += date + ";";
        tag1 = 1;


}

Comment: But this is giving error

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use $find(CalBeh)._selectedDate not just CalBeh._selectedDate in your function. You get error because CalBeh is string not calendar object.

EDIT:
In your javascript events functions (dateselect and calendarhidden) you have 'cntrl' parameter. This is actual calendar object.

Instead of doing $find and using behavior id you can do that to get selected date:

var date = cntrl._selectedDate

Comment: Even though using in this way $find(CalBeh)._selectedDate also not working